# How to change the selected text in a drop down list in rails application based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a select drop down box with a list of currencies.
To make it easier for users, I want to change the default selected value in the drop down when the page loads based on the user country (will use [geoip](https://rubygems.org/gems/geoip) gem for that)
So I will be writing this ruby code:

```
$country = GeoIp.geolocation(request.remote_ip, :precision => :country)
```

How to change the selected value of the drop down list box based on the $country value?
Should I do that with Javascript? or with rails forms helper?? And what is the code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `<option>` element that has the country as `selected='selected'`.  How you do that depends on how you built the option list.

For example, [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) takes the selected element as the 2nd argument.

```
options_for_select(['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma'], 'Beta')
# => <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
# => <option value="Beta" selected="selected">Beta</option>
# => <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your $country variable has a matching country code in your Country table, you could do something like this.

```
select_tag "currency", options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, "country_code", "currency_name", $country)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this:

```
<%= f.select :someobj, options_for_select({ "Basic" => "$20", "Plus" => "$40" }, $country ) %>
```

It will give you:

```
<select name="someobj">
 <option value="$20">Basic</option>
 <option value="$40" selected="selected">Plus</option>
</select>
```

Note use of Selected here.